# Replace particular file content in nodejs

Tags: javascript, fs

I want to replace a particular line using javascript with new content.
This is the file content,

```
SERVER=1055@localhost

GROUP_SERVERS=2325@localhost

LINE_IAM_INTERESTED=KTYUIERVW:2800

FILE_PATH="C:\Program Files\somefile\Shared Files\"
```

In this line, `LINE_IAM_INTERESTED=KTYUIERVW:2800` .I want to replace `KTYUIERVW` with `KJHTERDY` and `2800` with `78945`

I have shown what I tried using fs appendfilesync

```
fs.appendFileSync('file_name').toString().split('\n').forEach(function(line){
    app.console.log("called append");
    var sEntry = line.split("=");
    if (sEntry.length == 2) {
      if (sEntry[0] == "LINE_IAM_INTERESTED") {
      app.console.log("found one!!!!");
      }
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try READ -> REPLACE -> WRITE flow:

```
fs.writeFileSync('file_name', fs.readFileSync('file_name').replace('KTYUIERVW:2800', 'KJHTERDY:78945'))
```

Comment: writeFileSync needs the file path also.

Answer (score 0):

`appendFile` and `appendFileSync` are used for adding to the end of the file. Although you can do it as a one liner as shown in the other answer, I've kept the structure of your code the same. Here you want to read the data, modify it then re-write it. Using the block of code you have, you can modify it to use `readFileSync` and `writeFileSync`.

```
let newData = fs.readFileSync('file_name', 'utf-8').split('\n').map(line => {
  let sEntry = line.split('=')
  if (sEntry.length == 2) {
    if (sEntry[0] == "LINE_IAM_INTERESTED") {
      console.log("found one!!!!");
      return sEntry[0] + '=' + 'KJHTERDY:78945'
    }
  }
  return line
}).join('\n')

fs.writeFileSync('file_name', newData)
```

I've swapped the `forEach` for `map` which lets us change the array data by returning the desired value. The new array is then joined back together and written back to the file.